# Making VMware workstation install tools nag screen go away

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

A Windows XP host running VMware 7.1.4 keeps asking to install VMware tools for a Ubuntu guest and I select do not ask again but it continues to ask every-time VMware and that specific guest are started. I do not want to install tools for this guest. Any ideas on how to disable the annoying banner that usually pops up from the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Do you safely shutdown the guest and the VMware on the host? Have you looked into the options of VMware? Is there a specific reason not to install the tools?

Comment: +1 I know it doesn't answer your question, but in general the tools will make the VM much more [responsive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Tools), is there a specific reason to not install them?

Comment: I do always shutdown the guest before closing VMware. I use the guest for analysis of software, some of which is VM aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "do not ask" checkbox isn't being honored, it's a bug. Report it to VMware, either via support or their community forums.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, figured as much.